# How to use filter_input with array?

Tags: php, php-7

I tried to use `filter_input` to load my POST value into a variable:

```
$tmp = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "p_member");    // fails
```

**Output:**

```
bool(false)
```

I also tried `$tmp = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, "p_member");    // fails`

**Output:**

```
bool(false)
```

But this works:

```
$tmp = (array)@$_POST['p_member'];
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Your answer is always here
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php

Comment: To add on to @Azael's comment, use the `FILTER_REQUIRE_ARRAY` option

Comment: @Das_Geek, I tried `$tmp2 = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "p_member", FILTER_REQUIRE_ARRAY);` result -> `bool(false)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is an answer based on [link](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php)

> If your $_POST contains an array value:
>
> ```
> $_POST  = array(
>   'var' => array('more', 'than', 'one', 'values')
> );
> ```
>
> you should use FILTER_DEFAULT AND FILTER_REQUIRE_ARRAY option:
>
> ```
> var_dump(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'var', FILTER_DEFAULT , FILTER_REQUIRE_ARRAY));
> ```
>
> Otherwise it returns false.

Comment: Thx, we have to use both `FILTER_DEFAULT , FILTER_REQUIRE_ARRAY` to make it work.